# AssertJ: make assertion that all Assert objects were asserted upon

Tags: java, testing, junit, assertj

When using the AssertJ library, I'm interested in being able to assert that all `org.assertj.core.api.Assert` objects had an actual assertion made on them. That is, a test such as the following should fail because it is clearly a mistake:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

// ... elided ...

@Test
public void unfinishedAssertion() {
    assertThat("str");
}
```

Is there a way to configure this with AssertJ, or to make this assertion in a JUnit `@After` method?

My only thought is to provide a static factory like `assertThat` that returns a proxy, delegating all method invocations to the underlying Assert, and using an After method to assert that the proxy had at least one invocation with a method that was not `Assert#as` or `Assert#withFailMessage`, etc., but this seems cumbersome and unnecessary as the library should provide this functionality itself.

Comment: Mockito, for example, does a great job of reducing potential mistakes by throwing an exception when a stubbing is unfinished: `Mockito.when(obj.toString());` will fail a test

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the best way is to use findbugs/spotbugs to warn you about this kind of misuse, see https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-incorrect-usage for details.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a helpful link, static analysis was also the recommendation by a colleague. Does AssertJ have plans to support this as a situation that throws an exception though?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy way to do that in the library but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: this should help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406872/verify-that-assertions-have-been-called-in-assertj?rq=1