# ArchUnit: Prevent assertJ statements without assertion

Tags: testing, assertj, archunit

Is it possible to create an ArchUnit rule which prevents AssertJ statements without an assertion?

For exampel: This AssertJ statement is perfectly ok, because it has both a `assertThat` part and an assertion.

```java
assertThat(frodo.getName()).isEqualTo("Frodo");
```

I need a ArchUnit rule which will let the build fail when something like this is found:

```java
assertThat(frodo.getName());
```

This is a `assertThat` statement without an assertion. This line of code will never throw an Assertion exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that ArchUnit can catch such statements, but some static code analysis tools can, cf. [Verify that assertions have been called in Assertj](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49406872/).

Comment: I agree with Manfred, here's what our doc says https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-incorrect-usage